# Show results based on two items from array or more

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I've been struggling for hours now trying to figure out, how to display data based on array items using linq c#.

In short i am displaying data based on results from a querystring that passes into an array.
this works great with one array item.

but if i navigate to another page that has two or more array items, i want to be able to say only show me results that contains x,y,z. Code below:

```
public static List<business.Resource> getResourcesFromTags(string[] tags)
{
    var db = new Entities();
    List<business.Resource> resources = (
        from rt in db.tbl_ResourceTag
        where tags.Any(t =>t.Equals(rt.tbl_Tag.Name))
        select new Resource { 
            bookmark = rt.tbl_Resource.Bookmark, 
            dateAdded = rt.tbl_Resource.dateAdded,  
            text = rt.tbl_Resource.text, 
            uploadedFile = rt.tbl_Resource.uploadedFile, 
            uploadedImage = rt.tbl_Resource.uploadedImage, 
            resourceID = rt.tbl_Resource.ResourceID, 
            filePath = rt.tbl_Resource.filePath,  
            imagePath = rt.tbl_Resource.imagePath, 
            downloadCount = rt.tbl_Resource.downloads 
        }).Distinct().ToList();

    return resources;
}
```

So to re-cap if there is more than one array item, i want to be able to show data contains just those items. very difficult to explain.

Comment: whats the wrong in this code, your english is not good, i did nt got what you want?

Comment: "your English is not good" - I don't know if that's a joke or not. My problem is that I want to pass multiple array items to one column. Example: 'code' tags.Any(t =>t.Equals(rt.tbl_Tag.Name) & tags.Any(x => x.Equals(rt.tbl_Tag.Name) 'code' So in essence it fetches data only with two array items, currently it fetches all with any of the array items. It's difficult to explain.

Comment: this query is not returning desired results?